# Srapi - retrieve 1-n property from the Lifecycle call back model parameter

Tags: node.js, mongoose, strapi

i am using Strapi for a prototype and i am meeting the following issue. I have created a new content type "Checklist" and i added in it a relation property 1 to many with the User model provided by the users-permissions plugin. 
Then i wanted to add some custom logic on the lifecycle call back, in beforeSave and in beforeUpdate from which i would like to access the user assigned to the Checklist.

The code looks like that:

```
{
var self = module.exports = {
  // Before saving a value.
  // Fired before an `insert` or `update` query.

  generateLabel : (model) => {
    var label = "";

    var day = _moment(model.date,_moment.ISO_8601).year();
    var month = _moment(model.date,_moment.ISO_8601).day();
    var year = _moment(model.date,_moment.ISO_8601).month();

    console.log(model);
    if (model.user) {
      label = `${model.user}-${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }else{
      label = `unassigned-${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }

    return label;
```

I call the method generateLabel from the callback. It works, but my model.user always returned undefined. It is a 1-n property. I can access model.date property (one of the field i have created) without any issue, so i guess the pbs is related to something i have to do to populate the user relation, but i am not sure on how to proceed.

When i log the model object, the console display what i guess is a complete mongoose object but i am not sure where to go from there as if i try to access the property that i see in the console, i will always reach an undefined.

Thanks in advance for your time, i use the following

strapi: 3.0.0-alpha.13.0.1
nodejs: v9.10.1
mongodb: 3.6.3
macos high sierra

Answer (score 0):

Also running into the similar / same issue, I think this has to do with the user permissions plugin, and having to use that to access the User model.  Or I thought about trying to find the User that’s associated with the id of the newly created record.  I’m trying to use AfterCreate.  Anyone that could shed some light on this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It's because relational attributes are not send in `create` fonction (See your `checklist` service `add` function).

Relations are handled in an other function `updateRelations`.

The thing you can do is to send `values` in `Checklit.create()`